# Convergence of Sum of Squares of Gaussian Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I am trying to prove the following statement:

> Let $X_{n}$ be a sequence of independent Gaussian variables, with respective
>   mean $\mu_{n}$, and variance $\sigma_{n}^{2}$. Prove that $$\sum_{n} X_{i}^{2}\,\, \text{converges in } L_{1} \iff  \sum_{n} \mu_{n}^{2}  + \sigma_{n}^{2} < \infty $$

Comment: You should also include what you tried, background you know, etc.  See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960

Answer (score 1):

Denote $Y_n := \sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2$.
$$E[Y_n] = \sum_{i=1}^n\mu_i^2+\sigma_i^2$$
I hope it is clear that $L^1$ convergence of $Y_n$ implies convergence of the sum above. For the reverse implication, note that
$$E[Y_{n+1} \mid \mathcal{F}_n] = Y_n + \mu_{n+1}^2 +\sigma_{n+1}^2$$
Here $\mathcal{F}_n = \sigma(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$. Obviously, $Y_n$ is a submartingale. $E[Y_n] < \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu_i^2 +\sigma_i^2 < \infty$. So then we can apply Doob's convergence theorem to get that $Y_n$ converges almost surely. By evaluating $E[Y_n^2]$ (Here we use Gaussianity and independence) you can show that $(Y_n)$ is uniformly integrable. Hence we have $L^1$ convergence.